# Client is sending 'udp port 68 unreachable' in response to DHCP ACK - why?

Tags: dhcp

Please help me understand the following DHCP traffic. I've put my comments below each packet:

```
15:49:52.968450 d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 590: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 576)
0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec, length 548, xid 0x993a7913, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-Ethernet-Address d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
        MSZ Option 57, length 2: 576
        Parameter-Request Option 55, length 7: 
          Default-Gateway, Subnet-Mask, Option 252, NTP
          Domain-Name, Domain-Name-Server, Hostname
        Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec
        Hostname Option 12, length 16: "client-D7EB"
```

Client is discovering...

```
15:49:52.969227 bc:cf:4f:47:e5:14 > d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41683, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 48)
192.168.128.1 > 192.168.128.75: ICMP echo request, id 40432, seq 0, length 28
```

Server sent a PING (why? in order to find out if the client is responding on this IP?)

```
15:49:53.000717 bc:cf:4f:47:e5:14 > d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 16, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
192.168.128.1.67 > 192.168.128.75.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x993a7913, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Your-IP 192.168.128.75
      Client-Ethernet-Address d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Offer
        Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 192.168.128.1
        Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 7200
        Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 192.168.128.1
        Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.248.0
        Domain-Name Option 15, length 10: "xxxx.local"
        Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 192.168.128.1
```

Server sent a DHCP offer.

```
15:49:53.056204 d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec > 33:33:00:00:00:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 62: (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 8) :: > ff02::2: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router solicitation, length 8
```

Not sure what the above packet was all about.

```
15:49:53.106969 d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec > bc:cf:4f:47:e5:14, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 54777, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 48)
192.168.128.75 > 192.168.128.1: ICMP echo reply, id 40432, seq 0, length 28
```

Client did answer the PING from before.

```
15:49:53.136929 d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 590: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 576)
0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec, length 548, xid 0x993a7913, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-Ethernet-Address d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Request
        Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 192.168.128.75
        Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 192.168.128.1
        MSZ Option 57, length 2: 576
        Parameter-Request Option 55, length 7: 
          Default-Gateway, Subnet-Mask, Option 252, NTP
          Domain-Name, Domain-Name-Server, Hostname
        Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec
        Hostname Option 12, length 16: "client-D7EB"

15:49:53.138312 bc:cf:4f:47:e5:14 > d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 16, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
192.168.128.1.67 > 192.168.128.75.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x993a7913, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Your-IP 192.168.128.75
      Client-Ethernet-Address d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: ACK
        Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 192.168.128.1
        Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 7200
        Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 192.168.128.1
        Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.248.0
        Domain-Name Option 15, length 10: "xxxx.local"
        Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 192.168.128.1
```

Client requested IP 192.168.128.75 and server acknowledged that.

```
15:49:53.176504 d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec > bc:cf:4f:47:e5:14, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 370: (tos 0xd0, ttl 64, id 54799, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 356)
192.168.128.75 > 192.168.128.1: ICMP 192.168.128.75 udp port 68 unreachable, length 336
    (tos 0x10, ttl 16, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
```

Now the client sent a port unreachable ICMP response, why? And to which packet is this the response?

```
    192.168.128.1.67 > 192.168.128.75.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x993a7913, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Your-IP 192.168.128.75
      Client-Ethernet-Address d8:0b:9a:15:27:ec
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: ACK
        Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 192.168.128.1
        Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 7200
        Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 192.168.128.1
        Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.248.0
        Domain-Name Option 15, length 10: "xxxx.local"
        Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 192.168.128.1
```

Server is sending the ACK again... and from here on the whole thing is just repeating over and over.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you elaborate?

Comment: You need to look at the rules of the host firewall. If you don't know what to look for, post it here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually there is no firewall involved in this.

Comment: How is it going now?